# Powershell: Pull URL out of String

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

I am pulling a string  from a text file that looks like:

```
C:\Users\users\Documents\Firefox\tools\Install.ps1:37:    Url = "https://somewebsite.com"
```

I need to some how remove everything except the URL, so it should look like:

```
https://www.somewebsite.com
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
$Urlselect = Select-String -Path "$zipPath\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1"  -Pattern "url","Url"-List # Selects URL download path
$Urlselect = $Urlselect -replace ".*" ","" -replace ""*.","" # remove everything but the download link
```

but this didn't seam to do anything. I am thinking that its going to have to do with regex but I am not sure how to put it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) with the `-Regex` and `-File` options:

```
$url = switch -regex -file "$zipPath\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1" { 
  ' Url = "(.*?)"' { $Matches[1]; break } 
}
```

- `-file` makes `switch` loop over all lines of the specified file.
- `-regex` interprets the branch conditionals as [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions), and the automatic `$Matches` variable can be used in the associated script block (`{ ... }`) to access the results of the match, notably, what the 1st (and only) capture group in the regex (`(...)`) captured - the URL of interest.
- `break` stops processing once the 1st match is found. (To continue matching, use `continue`).

---

If you do want to use `Select-String`:

```
$url = Select-String -List ' Url = "(.*?)"' "$zipPath\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1" |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

Note that the `switch` solution will perform much better.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `Select-String -Path "$zipPath\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1" -Pattern "url","Url"`

`Select-String` is case-*insensitive*  by default, so there's no need to specify case variations of the same string. (Conversely, you must use the `-CaseSensitive` switch to force case-*sensitive* matching).

Also note that `Select-String` doesn't output the matching line *directly*, as a *string*, but as a [match-information objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo); to get the matching line, access the `.Line` property<sup>[1]</sup>.

> `$Urlselect -replace ".*" ","" -replace ""*.",""`

`".*" "` and `""*."` result in *syntax errors*, because you forgot to *escape* the _embedded `"` as `` `" ``.

Alternatively, use `'...'` (single-quoted *literal* strings), which allows you to embed `"` as-is and is generally preferable for regexes and replacement operands, because there's no confusion over what parts PowerShell may interpret up front (string expansion).

Even with the escaping problem solved, however, your `-replace` operations wouldn't have worked, because `.*"` matches *greedily* and therefore up to the *last* `"`; here's a corrected solution with *non-greedy* matching, and with the replacement operand omitted (which makes it default to the empty string):

```
PS> 'C:\...ps1:37: Url = "https://somewebsite.com"' -replace '^.*?"' -replace '"$'
https://somewebsite.com
```

- `^.*?"` non-greedily replaces everything up to the *first* `"`.
- `"$` replaces a `"` at the end of the string.

However, you can do it with a *single* `-replace` operation, using the same regex as with the `switch` solution at the top:

```
PS> 'C:\...ps1:37: Url = "https://somewebsite.com"' -replace '^.*?"(.*?)"', '$1'
https://somewebsite.com
```

`$1` in the replacement operand refers to what the 1st capture group (`(...)`) captured, i.e. the bare URL; for more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Note that there's a green-lit feature suggestion - not yet implemented as of Windows PowerShell Core 6.2.0 - to allow `Select-String` to emit strings directly, using the proposed `-Raw` switch - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7713</sup>

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful, @revgirl2012; my pleasure. Good luck; I hope you'll learn to enjoy PowerShell; it may take a while, but it's worth it.